# Android class to connect to MySQL on webserver?

Tags: android, mysql, class

I was wondering, whether there is a solution to grab values from a database without involving a php-script? Like a MySQL-Class to do all that work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but you really don't want to.  To make that work, your SQL server would need to have an open port in your firewall-  that means anyone anywhere could connect directly to it.  That's really insecure.

Comment: okay I see, so the most common way is to realize each and every database-query with a php script behind?

Comment: Yes (or any other language, but php is a common one).  That way only your http server is directly accessible to the world.  This helps in two ways-  first the servers themselves are generally more secure.  And second, it makes it harder for them to hack and get or alter your data, as compared to just defacing a web server.  The first is much harder to recover from than the second.

Comment: well how do I protect the data from being read by anyone? like for instances when I want to grab a certain devicetoken from my database I would have to access it by `http://www.domain.de/grabtoken.php?userid=123`. What would keep all the people in the world from just calling that url, too?

Comment: A combination of things can help with that.  First, don't use consecutive id numbers-  use random unique ids so they can't be guessed.  Second, require some authentication data-  preferably a username and password, if that isn't possible a large unknown key.  Third, use https not http so the connection is encrypted and they can't just sniff that key.

Comment: how do I use https instead of http? just changing the url?

Comment: On the android side yes.  On the server side there may be more work to do, but probably not if you just have a default hosting setup-  they usually setup https too

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can add a webservice to return JSON content on your server.

Here you can find a class i coded to get your JSONResponse as String :
[Java : a WebService asking embeded in a AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22694400/java-a-webservice-asking-embeded-in-a-asynctask/22694859?noredirect=1#comment34577374_22694400)

Take a look at paresh-mayani comment, library sounds awesome.

Comment: hey, do you know how to protect the data from being read by anyone? like for instances when I want to grab a certain devicetoken from my database I would have to access it by http://www.domain.de/grabtoken.php?userid=123. What would keep all the people in the world from just calling that url, too?

Comment: You may add some kind of an apiKey like google use to do (but a secret key in your case)

Comment: like have in that php script a check ? if `($_GET['key'] == "xyz") ...`
and the url in my app adds that key to the url?

Comment: Exactly what i was thinking

Comment: okay, well I thought about this method too but I was thinking this is thought a little too laterally..

Comment: You can create a crypted key each time you pass data, based on a fixed string to received eg :
Device encrypt "if you read this, we are ok to communicate"
you send from the device key="2:jduIfuNgI"
this mean you encrypted you string with a personal algorithm using encrypting key 2.
Then you decrypt the parameter on the server, then you must recover the encrypted string.
if you recover "if you read this, we are ok to communicate" then you can proceed

Comment: i'll consider this for later. for now I'll use a static key.