# how check post method if secceded in android?

Tags: android, http-post

i'am trying to log in into a website with post method ... how can i check if i logged in or not !!?

```
public void postData() {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://svuonline.org/isis/index.php");
try {if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_name", user.getText().toString()));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_pass",password.getText().toString()));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) { } 
catch (IOException e) { }
catch (Exception e) { }
}
```

Comment: Also, check out [Asynchronous Http Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/). We have been using it for a while in production and works really well!

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there! You already have the response in HttpResponse response, all you need to do is check the status code of the call.

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

responseCode should be equal to HttpStatus.SC_OK if everything went fine. You can also get the body of the response:

```
ResponseHandler<String> mHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
String body = mHandler.handleResponse(response);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i like your way but i try it like this :
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
         int responseCode=response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
         if(responseCode==HttpStatus.SC_OK){
          Toast.makeText(this, responseCode+" "+HttpStatus.SC_OK+" logged", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }else{
          Toast.makeText(this, responseCode+" "+HttpStatus.SC_OK+" not logged", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }

but it always give me logged even if there is no text or wrong or right ... always give me logged

Comment: Could it be that the server is responding with code 200 (OK) and a message saying "not logged in" or something, instead of responding with code 400 or 401?

Comment: even i try it on facebook post  : HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1");
  and it give me 200 which it mean ok for server response ... i need a way to know if i'am logged in successfully or not !!!

Comment: Have you checked what you are getting in the body of the response? Can you share that?

Comment: i think i have to search about sessions ... i'll search ... if you know anything about it tell me please ... thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a class i coded to get your server response as String : [Java : a WebService asking embeded in a AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22694400/java-a-webservice-asking-embeded-in-a-asynctask)

How to use is provided, just replace

```
WebServiceAsyncTask.GET
```

by

```
WebServiceAsyncTask.POST
```

and specify your parameters.

then you'll have to inspect the server response.



Take a look at paresh-mayani comment, library sounds awesome.