# How to retrieve data from mysql database for android application

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am sakthi...I would have retrieve data from database but can't to display it in android emulator.if am edit my code it shows error as file was stopped working.I would be fault in json to handle the data.if anyone knows pls help me...

```
public class Reportcard extends Activity
{
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();


     @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.reportcard);
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);             
                 String result = null;
                InputStream is = null;
                Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
                String id=(String)b.get("a");
                EditText e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                EditText e2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                EditText e3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
                EditText e4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
                EditText e5=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5);
                EditText e6=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText6);                
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id",id));
                    try
                    {
                        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/marks.php");
                        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        is = entity.getContent();
                        Log.e("log_tag", "connection success ");
                    }
                catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                //convert response to string
                    try{
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        String line = null;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
                        {
                                sb.append(line + "\n");

                        }
                        is.close();

                        result=sb.toString();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                       Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Input reading fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                //parse json data
                try{


                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
                        String ch=object.getString("re");
                        if(ch.equals("success"))
                        {

                           JSONObject no = object.getJSONObject("0");
                           String a=no.getString("cg");
                        String w= no.getString("mpc");
                        String x=no.getString("dwdm");
                       // String my = NumberFormat.getInstance().format(x);
                        String e=no.getString("dsp");
                        String y=no.getString("tqm");
                        String z=no.getString("eefa");
                       //String myString = NumberFormat.getInstance().format(e);
                        e1.setText(a);
                        //tex1.setText(w);
                        e2.setText(w);
                        e3.setText(e);
                        e4.setText(x);
                        e5.setText(y);
                        e6.setText(z);
                        //e1.setText(z);

                          }


                        else
                        {

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Record is not available.. Enter valid number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }


                }
                catch(JSONException e)
                {
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "JsonArray fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
          }
     }
```

This was my logcat errors...

```
03-29 14:09:08.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1057): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-29 14:09:08.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1057): Process: com.example.hell, PID: 1057
03-29 14:09:08.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1057): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hell/com.example.hell.Reportcard}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-29 14:09:08.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
03-29 14:09:08.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
03-29 14:09:08.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-29 14:09:08.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
03-29 14:09:08.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-29 14:09:08.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-29 14:09:08.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
03-29 14:09:08.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-29 14:09:08.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-29 14:09:08.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
03-29 14:09:08.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
03-29 14:09:08.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-29 14:09:08.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1057): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-29 14:09:08.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at com.example.hell.Reportcard.onCreate(Reportcard.java:107)
03-29 14:09:08.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
03-29 14:09:08.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-29 14:09:08.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
03-29 14:09:08.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Android http request must be executed in Handler or AsyncTask :

See a class i have coded : [Java : a WebService asking embeded in a AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22694400/java-a-webservice-asking-embeded-in-a-asynctask)

Uses example provided.

your problem is that you use `response.getEntity();` before your actually get the server response.